# FFMPEG resizes processed video

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, terminal, command

I have this simple code, whcih compresses videos to mp4. Everythign works well but when looking at the final video, it is upscaled higher. Example would be an original video file of 1920 × 1080 turns out to be 4096 × 2160. I do not want this to happen, instead if  FFMPEG finds a video of 720x1080,1920x180 etc.. it should keep the original video size, and not alter.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#find . \( -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.MOV" \);
#do echo $i; done
for i in $(find . -name '*.mov' -or -name '*.MOV'); do 
ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4";
rm "$i"
done
```

Comment: ffmpeg should preserve the width x height by default without you having to add any options. Get rid of the loop: only include the loop code when you verify that ffmpeg works as expected. Run `ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4`, copy **all** of the text from the console output, [edit] your question and paste the log text. The log text will show what is happening. Also, if you want to re-mux MOV to MP4 and avoid re-encoding use `ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy output.mp4` (assuming the input video and audio formats are compatible with MP4).

Answer (score 1):

You can resize/scale/change resolution of a video using FFMPEG quite easily. You can find it [here](https://ottverse.com/change-resolution-resize-scale-video-using-ffmpeg/). I'm not sure if this helps but there is an example there on how to specify its width/height but keep the Aspect ratio the same

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I do not want the size to change. it seems FFMPEG is changing it without me giving it commands to do so